# Python Selenium wait for Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

My Website contains a Table with two rows:

```
<table>
 <tr><td>Content</td><td>Content</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Content</td><td>Content</td></tr>
</table>
```

And i want to wait as long the Table was updated by JS and contains now three rows:

```
<table>
 <tr><td>Content</td><td>Content</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Content</td><td>Data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Content</td><td>Content</td></tr>
</table>
```

Selenium should find the second row with the Second column and get the Data. How i can realize that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium - wait until element is present, visible and interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable)

Comment: @tbhaxor Thanks for your Comment. This help me a little bit. That answers me how i can wait for the row. But how i can check if is the second row of three rows? I cant identify the Rows on other ways.

Comment: @DrEm8ee : If you know what's value of `Data` then it is possible using wait.

Comment: @KunduK I know that a String is expectect. I hope i have understood what you mean.

Comment: you can use getElements() to retrieve an array of <tr> elements.  If the array's count is not 3, call it again.... (similar to catching Stale Element exceptions and re-calling if caught)